# Run Metasploit module against several IPs

Tags: metasploit

I'm trying to run a module against several IPs. It happens that usually we can use RHOSTS file:/file.txt but in this case, that option is not available.

I have tried this https://www.pentestpartners.com/security-blog/scripting-metasploit-to-exploit-a-group-of-hosts-a-how-to/

My iter_rc.rc file is like this

```
<ruby>

hostsfile="/root/folder/hosts_file.txt"
hosts=[]
File.open(hostsfile,"r") do |f|
f.each_line do |line|
hosts.push line.strip
end
end
# prepare the handler and console
self.run_single("resource /root/folder/con_cmd_file.txt")
# iterate through each host and run the exploit
hosts.each do |rhost|
self.run_single("set rhost #{rhost}")
self.run_single("exploit -j -z") end

</ruby>
```

and my con_cmd_file.txt is like this

```
use  <module>
setg autorunscript multi_console_command -rc /root/folder/met_cmd_file.txt
setg lhost <local ip>
set ExitOnSession false
run
set target 1
set disablepayloadhandler true
```

How can I do it?

I'm getting the following errors

```
[-] Exploit failed: One or more options failed to validate: RHOST.
[*] Exploit completed, but no session was created.
resource (/root/folder/con_cmd_file.txt)> set target 1
target => 1
resource (/root/folder/con_cmd_file.txt)> set disablepayloadhandler true
disablepayloadhandler => true
rhost => ip1
[-] Exploit failed: An invalid argument was specified. Invalid target index.
rhost => ip2
[-] Exploit failed: An invalid argument was specified. Invalid target index.
rhost => ip3
[-] Exploit failed: An invalid argument was specified. Invalid target index.
rhost => ip4
[-] Exploit failed: An invalid argument was specified. Invalid target index.
```

Comment: Which module are you trying to run?

Comment: its a module from I took from exploit-db